# Google integration to amazon cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-plus, amazon-cognito

I have got the access tokens from Google+ and Facebook. Facebook integration is successful and it returns the `cognitoId` when the param is defined as follows:

```
Logins:{
    'graph.facebook.com':token
}
```

But 500 error is given when I use:

```
Logins:{
    'accounts.google.com':token //access_token received from google 
}
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `id_token` from google, not the `access_token`. You can ready more about how to integrate with google in the Amazon Cognito [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/google/).